# Angular service and pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

How do you use angularjs service to call pouchdb and return the data to the controller?  I have been working on a ionic app with pouchdb for local storage.  I have a simple crud app built in a controller.  Now I want to start to move the pouchdb calls into a service.  I haven’t been able to get back data from the service.  How would I use a service to call pouchdb to get all docs and return it to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that I think could work very well for Angular services is [this one](http://pouchdb.com/2015/02/28/efficiently-managing-ui-state-in-pouchdb.html). It describes a method for keeping an in-memory array synced with the result of PouchDB's `allDocs()`.

Since it's an array that automatically stays synced with PouchDB, you can just do an `ng-repeat` on it, and you're done. :)

Comment: Nolan, this is not really on-topic, but I'm looking for a complete, good best-practice implementation (a complete small/mid-size open-source or demo app) of angular-pouchdb. Would you please recommend one or two?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a year old, it deserves an answer.

You might want more than one service i.e. one to use in the controller and another for the backend database storage.  For example, in the controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.services')
        .factory('db',db);

    db.$inject = ['$db'];

    function db($db) {

        var data = {};              // set up a data object to receive document(s)

        return {
            getDoc: getDoc,
            getList: getList,
            save: save,
            saveBatch: saveBatch
            };


        // get a single document using the id
        function getDoc(id) {
            $db.getDoc(id)
                .then(
                    function onSuccess(doc) {
                        // success so update the view model
                        angular.extend(data,doc);                         // use angular.extend to shallow copy object so that it can be returned in full
                    },
                    function onError() {
                        // failure to get document                             
                    }
                );
            return data;
        }

        // retrieve a group of documents where key is the prefix of the data you want
        function getList(key) {
            $db.getList(key).then(
                function onSuccess(docs) {
                    // success so update the view model details
                    angular.forEach(docs.rows, function (value) {
                        this.push(value.doc);
                    }, data);
                    // now you can sort data or anything else you want to do with it

                },
                function onError() {
                    // no data found
                }
            );
            return data;
        }


        // save a single viewItem
        function save(viewItem) {
            $db.update(viewItem).then(
                function onSuccess() {                   
                    // success so update view model if required
                },
                function onError(e) {
                    console.log(e);         // unable to save
                }    
            );    
        }

        // save an array of viewItems
        function saveBatch(viewItems) {
            $db.updateBatch(viewItems).then(
                function onSuccess() {                   
                    // success so update the view model if required
                },
                function onError(e) {
                    console.log(e);         // unable to save
                }    
            );    
        }

    }
})();
```

For the backend, something like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.services')
        .factory('$db',$db);

    $db.$inject = ['$q'];

    function $db($q) {

        var db;

        return {
            setLocalDB: setLocalDB,
            update: update,
            updateBatch: updateBatch,
            getDoc: getDoc,
            getAllDocs: getAllDocs,
            getList: getList
        };

    // ------ DATABASE OPENING HANDLER(S) ------

        // set to any named database
       function setLocalDB(dbName) {
            db = new PouchDB(dbName);
            return db.info()
                .catch(failedCheck());             // returns a promise to either work or fail
        }

        // return a rejection for a failure
        function failedCheck() {
            return $q.reject();
        }

    // ------ DOCUMENT HANDLING ------     

        // update document but if errors occur recurse qUpdate until either complete or retries exhausted
        function update(doc) {
            var counter = 0;
            return $q.when(qUpdate(doc,counter));
        }

        // this routine works for both new and existing documents
        function qUpdate(doc,counter) {
            return db.put(doc)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('success - new document');                 
                })
                .catch(function(e) { 
                    console.log(e);                     // not a new document so try as a revision of existing document using _id to find
                    return db.get(doc._id)
                        .then(function(origDoc) {
                            doc._rev = origDoc._rev;                    // get document revision _rev
                            return db.put(doc,doc._id,doc._rev)
                                .then(function() {
                                    console.log('success - revision of document');
                                })
                                .catch(function(e){
                                    console.log(e);             // log error for failure
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(function(e){
                            console.log(e);                     // log error before we take any other action
                            counter ++;                         // increment counter, so we can limit retries (5 by default)
                            if (counter< 5) {
                                switch (e.status) {
                                    case 404:
                                        delete doc._rev;                        // remove revision information so we can see if this works
                                        return qUpdate(doc);                    // might be deleted so return revised document for retry                 
                                    case 409:
                                        return qUpdate(doc);                    // in conflict so try again
                                    default:
                                        try {
                                            throw new Error("cannot save: " + doc._id);     // cannot go any further so throw new error   
                                        } catch(err) {
                                            console.log(err);                               // log error for failure
                                        } 
                                }
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    throw new Error("cannot save" + doc._id);   // cannot go any further so throw new error 
                                } catch(err) {
                                    console.log(err);                           // log error for failure
                                } 
                            }
                        });    
                    });   
        }

        // update a document batch stored in an array
        function updateBatch(docs) {
            return $q.when(qUpdateBatch(docs));
        }

        // do the actual update of a batch
        function qUpdateBatch(docs) {
            db.bulkDocs(docs).then(function(res) {
                for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    if (res[i].status === 409) {
                        update(docs[i]);                 // in conflict so try this document separately
                    }
                }
            }).catch(function(e){
                console.log(e);                         // log error
            });  
        }

        // get the document as an angular promise and deal with it in host routine
        function getDoc(id)  {
            return $q.when(db.get(id));
        }

        // get all documents
        function getAllDocs() {
            return $q.when(db.allDocs({include_docs: true, attachments: false})); 
        }

        // get a batch of documents between a start and end key
        function getList(key) {
            return $q.when(db.allDocs({startkey: key, endkey: key + '\uffff', include_docs: true, attachments: false})); 
        }
    }
})();
```

In your main controller you would want to set the database:

```
   $db.setLocalDB('yourDB');
```

Hope this is what you were looking for?

In my own data services module I have other functions for remote database, event listeners, remove, sync, compact, destroy and so on.